# Attribute on struct default constructor

Tags: c#, struct, attributes, default-constructor

As structs cannot have explicit user-defined parameterless constructors e.g.

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public MyStruct() { … } // Not allowed!
}
```

I was wondering if and how I can apply an attribute to that exact constructor. 
In the end, what I want to do is this (best would be if the parameterless constructor could be private, but that's not allowed either):

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    [Obsolete("Do not call the constructor directly, use MyStruct.Get() instead.")]
    public MyStruct() { … }

    public static MyStruct Get
    {
      // Important initializing here.
    }
}
```

**Is there something like this fictional attribute target `[constructor: Obsolete()]` which allows for an attribute to be applied to the default constructor?**

EDIT: Some more information.

The situation is this: I need to use `MyStruct` for P/Invoke and cannot use a class. I want to warn the user that they shouldn't get an instance of `MyStruct` because it misses important initialization, and they should rather use a factory method instead.

Comment: If you want that level of control, then you're probably going to have to use a class instead of a struct.

Comment: @DavidG you're right, it would be dead-simple if it could be a class. However, since it will be used for P/Invoke it needs to be a struct.

Comment: It's kind of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), it would be great if you add some more details about your question and why you want to do such thing.

Comment: @SeM you're right, I was even thinking of mentioning that in my question as well. I will edit the question accordingly. Too bad I reached my daily vote limit; I would have upvoted your and Davids comment.

Comment: It won't really solve all problems, because struct can be initialized to default state without calling that constructor. And if that state is unacceptable to you - you have to verify manually then (obsolete constructor will not catch all problem cases).

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow It's ok, don't worry about that.

Comment: You can use a class for P/Invoke - what makes you think you can't? It gets marshalled by the marshaller either way. Unless it's a struct embedded in another struct.

Comment: @Evk You're right. I think you mean e.g. creating an array of `MyStruct`s or using `Activator.CreateInstance()` - I can't and don't want to prevent that, I just that I wanted to prevent errors by users wrongly considering that calling the constructor would be enough. It's difficult to put in words, I hope you do get what I want to say.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I read about that before, and I think this might be an option. I will have to restructure all my code though, but if that works, it would be really great.

Comment: We have almost always used classes for P/Invoke - but note that you will probably need to use `[StructLayout]` attributes to specify the layout for the marshaller if you use a class. (In my experience, I also needed to do that for structs in some cases.)

Comment: Consider that `MyStruct ms = default(MyStruct)` will create an empty `struct` without using `new`...

Comment: @MatthewWatson that won't be an issue; I also use `[StructLayout]` for the struct. I really think you're onto something - I hope your suggestion does work without breaking too much existing code. Anyways, thank you in advance.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I tried to use a class instead of a struct and it works perfectly fine with very little code changes. Mind = blown. Thank you very much for your comment, it made everything so much easier. I wish it was an answer so I could accept it and give you the reputation you deserve.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow That's fine, your thanks is more than enough recompense. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of struct is a ValueType, by its nature **you can't find any way**.

even you instantiated a struct or not, it will be instantiated.

`int x = new int();` is equivalent to `int x;`

and

`MyStruct s = new MyStruct();` is equivalent to `MyStruct s;`

Suppose you can find a way to warn about `MyStruct s = new MyStruct();`. any definition to `MyStruct s;` is also warned! Then there is no way.